# Appending list of optional elements

Tags: scala, sequence, scala-option

I need to make a sequence that, given a list containing optional list of strings, concatenates all of them to make a new list. This how my code looks like:

```
      res.foldLeft(Seq[Option[Seq[String]]]())((acc, v) => v match {
      case Some(x) => acc ++: Some(x)
      case None => acc
    })
```

where `res` is a list containing optional list elements such as :

```
List(Some(Seq(foo)), Some(Seq(bar)), None, Some(Seq(baz, blah)))
```

I get a compilation error at the sign `++:` saying:

```
  type mismatch; found : Iterable[Equals] required: Seq[Option[Seq[String]]]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just do:

```
res.flatten.flatten
```

first `flatten` will get rid of `None`s and expose the `Option`s and second one will perform the expected flattening operation on the `Seq`s

Answer (score 0):

I don't have scala installed on this box, but you could try using the 'map' function to remove the options out of the equation, then flatten the list of seq down to a single iterable.

Something like this:

```
res.map.flatten
```

As I understand it you would then end up with a Iterable containing 'foo', 'bar', 'sez', 'bar'.

I'll check this out a little later to test the syntax is correct and what I've written actually works..

Cheers, Aaron

**EDIT:** Got access to my scala terminal and this works:

```
res.map(s => s).flatten.flatten
```

Comment: 1. You need to pass a function for `map`. 2. `map(f).flatten` can be replaced with `flatMap(f)`.

Comment: True.. still learning the language myself in fact. The eventual answer  from @dimitrisli is nice, simple and elegant. Thank you for commenting, helps with my learning.

Comment: `map(s => s)` does nothing except creating a copy, it can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your types in `case Some(x) => acc ++: Some(x)` part is wrong.

`++:` operator expects a parameter of type `Seq[Option[Seq[String]]]` but you are providing a parameter of type `Option[Seq[String]]`.

*ps: If you can tell exactly the result you expect. I can improve this answer to help you to write the correct code you need.*